# How to limit the number of concurrent Windows HPC jobs?

Tags: c#, windows, scheduler, hpc

I need to limit the number of concurrent jobs that are running in an HPC cluster.

What would be the best way to do that?

Comment: Please provide details, such as what job system you're using, and how you want to limit them (via a GUI/MMC? through some program code? through WMI or some other API?)

Comment: I'm splitting a large processing task by creating several jobs [from code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853426(v=vs.85).aspx) to work with smaller chunks of data. I want a way to limit the number of jobs that will execute concurrently. Doesn't matter how it will be done really, as long as it's in HPC. I'm using an external limiter now that I'd like to replace.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

You can either have "Queued" scheduling which runs the jobs in order of the queue. If the first job was not using all cores, then another job would also start (and so on).

Or you can have "Balanced" which runs as many simultaneous jobs as possible with their minimum resource requirement. Then shares the remaining resource between the jobs based on their priority.

If you need to limit the number of simultaneous jobs (and not number of tasks) then I am guessing you have a bottleneck somewhere else. I would work on fixing the bottleneck.